# scala: How to pass an expanded list as varargs into a method?

Tags: scala, dictionary, variadic-functions

When creating a `Map` in scala, I call `Map(entities.map{e => e.id -> e})`, and I get:

```
found   : scala.collection.mutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Entity)]
required: (Int, Entity)
```

This is because the signature for `Map.apply` is: `def apply[A, B](elems: (A, B)*): CC[A, B]`,
which requires a varargs style argument.

Is there a way to convert the `IndexedSeq` so that it can be accepted via `Map.apply`?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Try this: `Map(entities.map{e => e.id -> e}:_*)`

Explicitly typing it as a varargs using `:_*` seems to work.

Answer (score 8):

Or this should work too:

```
entities.map{e => e.id -> e} toMap
```