# Scala: Can I convert an Option to varargs?

Tags: scala, variadic-functions, scala-option

I have an `Option`:

```
val myOption: Option[Int] = fooBar()
```

And a method that takes a varargs param:

```
def myMethod(a: String, b: Int*) = {...}
```

Is there any way to pass the option to the method as a varargs param? i.e. if the option is `Some(3)` then pass 3, and if it is `None` then pass nothing.

Experimenting with the answer to 
[scala: How to pass an expanded list as varargs into a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495428/scala-how-to-pass-an-expanded-list-as-varargs-into-a-method) I tried explicitly typing the argument:

```
myMethod("xyz", myOption: _*)
```

but the compiler complains that it requires a `Seq[Int]`. It seems that `Option` does not implement `Seq` and there is no predef implicit conversion.

Given that the compiler wants a `Seq`, I can of course pass `myOption.toList: _*`, but is there a nicer way?

Comment: What does your method require of a `Seq`?  It's possible you can write it with more general collection operations (i.e. foreach, map, filter, etc.)

Comment: @schmmd In this particular case, `myMethod` is part of a third-party library, so I have no choice but to use varargs. It it were my own code, I would probably just rewrite the method to take `Iterable[Int]` instead of `Int*`, and save myself all this trouble!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
myMethod("xyz", myOption.toSeq: _*)
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this will internally call `myOption.toList`, via the `Option` object's `implicit def option2Iterable` method?

Comment: @ChrisB Ouch! You are absolutely right... Yes, `toList` is better.