# How to "negative select" columns in spark's dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I can't figure it out, but guess it's simple. I have a spark dataframe df. This df has columns "A","B" and "C". Now let's say I have an Array containing the name of the columns of this df:

```
column_names = Array("A","B","C")
```

I'd like to do a `df.select()` in such a way, that I can specify which columns *not* to select.
Example: let's say I do not want to select columns "B". I tried

```
df.select(column_names.filter(_!="B"))
```

but this does not work, as

> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
>    cannot be applied to (Array[String])

So, [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#select(java.lang.String,%20scala.collection.Seq)) it says it should work with a Seq instead. However, trying

```
df.select(column_names.filter(_!="B").toSeq)
```

results in

> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
>    cannot be applied to (Seq[String]).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[Since Spark 1.4](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7280) you can use [`drop`](https://github.com/rakeshchalasani/spark/blob/ce2ec09ef702ad7191638299adf63e7af380ac18/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.scala#L865) method:

**Scala**:

```scala
case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Point(0, 0) :: Point(1, 2) :: Nil)
df.drop("y")
```

**Python**:

```py
df = sc.parallelize([(0, 0), (1, 2)]).toDF(["x", "y"])
df.drop("y")
## DataFrame[x: bigint]
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of this -- but then also I am still on spark 1.3.

Comment: I wonder if there any method to drop by column locations, something such as `df.drop(1)` or `df.drop(col(1))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg `df.drop(df.columns(i))`?

Comment: Thanks! Good idea, though it needs square brackets as in `df.drop(df.columns[i])`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Python after all? :)

Comment: Yeah, I had no choice cause had to get to production fast and couldn't find  enough docs in Scala :( I intend to move back to Scala within next several months or so.

Comment: @DavidArenburg :) In Python you can actually use `df.drop(df[i])` but Scala doesn't support that.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and solved it this way (oaffdf is a dataframe):

```
val dropColNames = Seq("col7","col121")
val featColNames = oaffdf.columns.diff(dropColNames)
val featCols = featColNames.map(cn => org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col(cn))
val featsdf = oaffdf.select(featCols: _*)
```

https://forums.databricks.com/questions/2808/select-dataframe-columns-from-a-sequence-of-string.html

Answer (score 5):

OK, it's ugly, but this quick spark shell session shows something that works:

```
scala> val myRDD = sc.parallelize(List.range(1,10))
myRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[17] at parallelize at <console>:21

scala> val myDF = myRDD.toDF("a")
myDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int]

scala> val myOtherRDD = sc.parallelize(List.range(1,10))
myOtherRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[20] at parallelize at <console>:21

scala> val myotherDF = myRDD.toDF("b")
myotherDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [b: int]

scala> myDF.unionAll(myotherDF)
res2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int]

scala> myDF.join(myotherDF)
res3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: int]

scala> val twocol = myDF.join(myotherDF)
twocol: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: int]

scala> val cols = Array("a", "b")
cols: Array[String] = Array(a, b)

scala> val selectedCols = cols.filter(_!="b")
selectedCols: Array[String] = Array(a)

scala> twocol.select(selectedCols.head, selectedCols.tail: _*)
res4: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int]
```

Providings varargs to a function that requires one is treated in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040382/scala-constructor-taking-either-seq-or-varargs) [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495428/scala-how-to-pass-an-expanded-list-as-varargs-into-a-method). The signature of select is there to ensure your list of selected columns is not empty – which makes the conversion from the list of selected columns to [varargs](http://daily-scala.blogspot.ch/2009/11/varargs.html) a bit more complex.

Answer (score 3):

For **Spark v1.4** and higher, using **`drop(*cols)`** -

Returns a new DataFrame without the specified column(s).

Example -

```
df.drop('age').collect()
```

---

For **Spark v2.3** and higher you could also do it using **`colRegex(colName)`** -

Selects column based on the column name specified as a regex and returns it as [Column](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column).

Example-

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c",  3)], ["Col1", "Col2"])
df.select(df.colRegex("`(Col1)?+.+`")).show()
```

Reference - [colRegex](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.colRegex), [drop](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.drop)

---

For older versions of Spark, take the list of columns in dataframe, then remove columns you want to drop from it (maybe using set operations) and then use `select` to pick the resultant list.

Answer (score 2):

```
val columns = Seq("A","B","C")

df.select(columns.diff(Seq("B")))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do as following

[image]

It uses Spark's ability to select columns using regular expressions.
And using negative look-ahead expression `?!`

In this case dataframe has columns a,b,c and regex excluding column b from the list.

Notice: you need to enable regexp for column name lookups using `spark.sql.parser.quotedRegexColumnNames`=`true` session setting. And requires Spark 2.3+

```
select `^(?!b).*` 
from (
   select 1 as a, 2 as b, 3 as c
)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29050754)

Comment: updated answer. thanks for the feedback. my original answer was over 5 years ago so I didn't have Spark 2.3 handy at that time :)

Answer (score 1):

In pyspark you can do

```
df.select(list(set(df.columns) - set(["B"])))
```

Using more than one line you can also do

```
cols = df.columns
cols.remove("B")
df.select(cols)
```

Comment: why not use .drop() ?