# Spark & Scala: “negative select” columns in spark's org.apache.spark.sql.row

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434886/how-to-negative-select-columns-in-sparks-dataframe) (which was solved using `drop()`) I have the same problem for the `spark.sql.row`. I checked [the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row), but wasn't able to figure it out on my own. I want to avoid a workaround like `toSeq()` if there's a cleaner alternative.

How do I retrieve all elements but a one given by index?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val row = Row(1, 1.2, 57.12, null)
val colIndexToBeExluded = 1
// how do I get all (3) columns but colIndexToBeExluded ?
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "get ... columns"? What do you want to end up with? An array? Another Row?

Comment: I concur with @TheArchetypalPaul . I'm not sure that I understand your question.

Comment: a `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector` would be the optimum output since I want to apply machine learning on the remaining columns.

Comment: Not sure I understand how that would work, since Vectors hold Doubles and your Row doesn't have any (and only one numeric value)

Comment: Changed question accordingly - thanks. I do have only numbers ideed.